# Bitmap Font data as array in C

Tags: fonts, conversion

I need to convert some X11 bitmap fonts to an array in C for a 128x64 OLED Display.

I saw some fonts like `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/9x15-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz`

The result should look like

```
/* Standard ASCII 6x8 font */
const char PROGMEM font6x8[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,// sp
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00, 0x00,// !
  0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00,// "
```

Are the tools for converting a pcf font to an array of chars in C?
Where are good resources for bitmap fonts?

Is there anything else I have missed?

Comment: I'm interested in this myself. If you do come across an answer, please share your solution here.

Comment: Why need to convert. Do you want to store the file in an array?

Comment: You have *.pcf.gz file and you want to create array in C, right? You should try to open the file, read it and convert bytes to hexadecimal format.

Comment: @totti: the `why` is already included in the Q: `for a 128x64 OLED Display`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `convert` as shown here: [C header file with bitmapped fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156872/2498790)

Probably there are a lot of commands to convert fonts to bitmap, but the [freetype API](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-toc.html) is easy enough to write your own with not much code.

Using the [freetype example](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/example1.c) I wrote something you can use as a start, it output an `.xbm` file (is a `c` file but you can use graphics programs like `gimp` to view/edit it).

Notiche that `gimp` also support export to `.xbm` with different bytes per pixel.

The `.xbm` exported by the example is a 1 bit per pixel format (1 black, 0 white), you need to edit the code in order to handle more colors (the freetype normally use a 8 bit gray scale bitmap buffer to render, if render mode is `FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL`, you may also need to remove the step with the temporary bitmap used to align the FT buffer to 1 byte).

The `to_bitmap` function is where the conversion from the FT buffer to the destination bitmap is done,

To build the example the `freetype` dev package is needed, on `Debian` (maybe also `Ubuntu`) use:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Simply `make` to build it.

Use the command with the font path as argument, the output is on `stdout`

`./font2c /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/9x15-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz >c-bmp-font.xbm`

`Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS += -O2 -Wall 
CFLAGS += $(shell freetype-config --cflags)
LIBS += $(shell freetype-config --libs)

font2c: font2c.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

clean:
    -rm -f font2c
```

`font2c.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include <ftbitmap.h>

#define WIDTH   640
#define BYTEWIDTH (WIDTH)/8
#define HEIGHT  480

static unsigned char image[HEIGHT][BYTEWIDTH];

static FT_Library library;
static FT_Face face;
static FT_Error err;
static FT_Bitmap tempbitmap;

static void to_bitmap( FT_Bitmap*  bitmap, FT_Int x, FT_Int y) {

    FT_Int  i, j, p, q;
    FT_Int  x_max = x + bitmap->width;
    FT_Int  y_max = y + bitmap->rows;

    for ( i = x, p = 0; i < x_max; i++, p++ ) {
        for ( j = y, q = 0; j < y_max; j++, q++ ) {
            if ( (i < 0) || (j < 0) || (i >= WIDTH || j >= HEIGHT) )
                continue;
            image[j][i >> 3] |= (bitmap->buffer[q * bitmap->width + p]) << (i & 7);
        }
    }
}

static void draw_glyph(unsigned char glyph, int *x, int *y) {
    FT_UInt  glyph_index;
    FT_GlyphSlot  slot = face->glyph;

    glyph_index = FT_Get_Char_Index( face, glyph );

    if ((err = FT_Load_Glyph( face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT ))) {
        fprintf( stderr, "warning: failed FT_Load_Glyph 0x%x %d\n", glyph, err);
        return;
    }

    if ((err = FT_Render_Glyph( face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_MONO ))) {
        fprintf( stderr, "warning: failed FT_Render_Glyph 0x%x %d\n", glyph, err);
        return;
    }

    FT_Bitmap_New(&tempbitmap);
    FT_Bitmap_Convert( library, &slot->bitmap, &tempbitmap, 1);

    to_bitmap( &tempbitmap, *x, *y );

    FT_Bitmap_Done( library, &tempbitmap );

    *x += slot->advance.x >> 6;
}

static void out_xbm(int w, int h) {
    int x, y;
    printf("#define BMP_width %d\n", WIDTH);
    printf("#define BMP_height %d\n", h);
    printf("static char BMP_bits[] = {\n");
    for (y=0; y < h; y++) {
        printf("\t");
        for (x=0; x < w; x++) {
            printf("0x%x, ", image[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n}\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *filename;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int g;

    memset (image, 0, BYTEWIDTH*HEIGHT);

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf( stderr, "usage: font2c [font]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    filename = argv[1];

    if ((err = FT_Init_FreeType( &library ))) {
        fprintf( stderr, "error: Init_Freetype failed %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((err = FT_New_Face( library, filename, 0, &face ))) {
        fprintf( stderr, "error: FT_New_Face failed %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (g = 0; g < 256; g++) {
        if (x+8 >= WIDTH) {
                x = 0;
                y += 15; // FIXME get ascender
        }
        draw_glyph(g, &x, &y);
    }

    out_xbm(BYTEWIDTH, HEIGHT);

    FT_Done_Face( face );
    FT_Done_FreeType( library );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Added to [github](https://github.com/xenogenesi/font2c)  with autotools support and facilities to generate the `.deb` package, _maybe_ I'll make some improvement in the future (having enough free time)

Answer (score 4):

It's quite easy to convert PSF (console) font to C include rather PCF (X11).
I think it will do the trick for you if you're looking for monospace bitmap font for simple embedded applications.

All you need is `psf2inc` from `psftools` package:

`$ psf2inc --psf1 font.psf font.inc`

Now `font.inc` holding all 256 ASCII characters:

```
0x36, 0x04,   /* Magic */
0x02,   /* Type */
0x0e,   /* Char size */
0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xfe,
0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0x00, 0x00,   /* 0 */
0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfc, 0xc6, 0xc6,
0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00,   /* 1 */
0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xfc, 0xc6,
0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00,   /* 2 */
```

And so on. After some editing you will get a nice header with monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

xxd is your best option :

```
xxd -i <myfile> > header.h
```